# Show child data in View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to show child data in view here I have two models Book (parent) and Author (child).
I want to show author name on view but in Book model I have Author object with null reference, but AuthorId has value 1.

I succeeded to get child values in controller when I got Book data with DbContext object I search for Author data, I don't know is this correct way because I am new with ASP.NET MVC or there exists better solution to connect data between parent and child data?

Here is my controller and model classes.

```
public ActionResult Book(int id)
{
    var book = dbContext.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == id);

    if(book.AuthorId != null)
    {
        book.Author = dbContext.Authors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == book.AuthorId);
    }

    return View(book);
}
```

Book model class.

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public decimal Score { get; set; }

    public Format Format { get; set; }

    public Language Language { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

And this child model Author

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

}
```

EDIT:
Solution is to use Include extension method which can be found in this namespace System.Data.Entity.

```
    public ActionResult Book(int id)
    {
        var book = dbContext.Books
                    .Include(a => a.Author)
                    .Include(p => p.ProductDetails)
                    .SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == id);

        return View(book);
    }
```

Comment: I discovered Include extension method and it works as charm :), using this namespace System.Data.Entity;

Answer (score 0):

Code does not seem to have any errors. Make sure your Database Table Column names match exactly with Property name. And try different ways of adding forign key in EF.

[Adding Foreign Key](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I worked same job as it show on page under this link. But when I get data through DbContext object in BookController I have all data except Author object, I also have AuthorId data which is in my case 1. I was wonder is there any way to get Author data while I getting data for Book.